# Angular ui-router: stop controller from reloading on press of back button in the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

It seems, by default, the controller of the previous state is reloaded when you press the back button in the browser to go to a previous state.
(this is not true in case of parent-child states)

How can I prevent that from happening?

Since I am not going to change any data in my current state which can affect the previous state, I don't want the previous state to reload again.

Here is a small plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xkQcEywRZVFmavW6eRGq?p=preview

There are 2 states: `home` and `about`. If you go to `about` state and then press back button, you will see that the `home` state controller is called again.

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'partial-home.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
       console.log('i was called');
    }
})
```

I believe this is the expected behavior, but I want to prevent it because my previous state (`home` in this case) is doing some visualizations which take some time to be created again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with a global controller like `GlobalCtrl` which is added to the `<body>` or `<html>` tag like `ng-controller="GlobalCtrl`.

Doing this will enable us to keep the scope of this `GlobalCtrl` throughout your single page Angular app (as you are using ui-router).

Now, inside your `GlobalCtrl` define something like this:

```
$rootScope.globalData = {preventExecution: false};

// This callback will be called everytime you change a page using ui-router state
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
    $scope.globalData.preventExecution = false;

    // Just check for your states here
    if (toState.name == "home" && fromState.name == "about") {
        $scope.globalData.preventExecution = true;
    }
});
```

Now, in your state configuration, you can use this `$scope.globalData.preventExecution;`

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'partial-home.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
       if ($scope.globalData.preventExecution) {
           return;
       }
       console.log('i was called');
    }
});
```

*Answer to the question*: **The scope that we refer in the GlobalCtrl and the scope that we use in the State controller, how are they related?**

Well, it is a very good question but it's simple. Every time a new scope is created  in Angular, it always inherits its parent scope (unless isolated). So when your `home` state controller instantiated, its scope created using parent state i.e. `$rootScope` here in this case and we are instantiating the `globalData` in the `$rootScope` which is an Object (an `Object` in Javascript can be used to it's any nested object. [Read this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)). So now when we are setting the `globalData.preventExecution` `true/false`, the same data can be used in the `$scope` of your `home` state controller. This is how both scopes are related or using the same data.

*Answer to the question*: **is there some flag or setting in the ui-router which can accomplish this in general**

If you want to achieve the above behaviour code for multiple states then you can write something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
    $scope.globalData.preventExecution = false;

    if (toState.name == "home" && fromState && fromState.preventHomeReExecution) {
        $scope.globalData.preventExecution = true;
    }
});
```

Now, your states can be written like this:

```
.state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    templateUrl: 'partial-about.html',
    preventHomeReExecution: true
})
.state('foo', {
    url: '/foo',
    templateUrl: 'partial-foo.html',
})
.state('bar', {
    url: '/bar',
    templateUrl: 'partial-bar.html'
    preventHomeReExecution: true
})
```

Basically, we are using `preventHomeReExecution: true` as a flag you wanted.

Comment: Deleted my answer since this one is more detailed.

Comment: It is working. I am not able to understand one thing though, the scope that we refer in the GlobalCtrl and the scope that we use in the State controller , how are they related? it seems like the same scope is injected to the state controller as well or is it because of the rootScope being inherited?

Comment: Also, this code is very particular and i would have to write something like this for many state interactions, is there some flag or setting in the ui-router which can accomplish this. for example , don't reload the controller on back press at all, whatever be the states.